# Expected value of a random composition of functions

Tags: probability, expected-value, function-and-relation-composition

Let's say I have two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. For simplicity let's say both functions are linear.

Let $C_m(x)$ be any function where $f$ and $g$ are composed with each other exactly $m$ times (so $C_m(x)$ is a Random Variable (function) across a space of $2^m$ such possible functions).

Is there any theory which can help predict $E[C_m(1)]$?

---

EXAMPLE

If $m=2$ , then we can have 4 possible values for $C_m(x)$, namely $f\circ g$ , $f\circ f$ , $g\circ f$ , $g\circ g$

Supposing  $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ and $g(x)=3x+1$, we then can compute each such function, we see the distribution of $C_2(x)$ is : $\{ 0.25x, 1.5x+1, 1.5x+.5, 9x+4\}$ upon which we find that $E[C_2(1)]=4.4375$.

---

Even harder, how can we predict, say,

$E[\frac{b}{1-a}]$
where
$a = \frac{C_m(1)-C_m(-1)}{2}$
$b = \frac{C_m(1)+C_m(-1)}{2}$

(One will note that this is the expectation of the value of $x$ which satisfies $C_m(x)=x$, under the conditions that $f$ and $g$ are both linear)

Comment: For $m$ affine functions $\ell_1, \ldots, \ell_m : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with respective slope, intercept pairs $\pi_1 = (a_1, b_1), \ldots, \pi_m = (a_m, b_m)$, their composition is $$(\ell_m \circ \cdots \circ \ell_1)(x) = \Big(\prod_{i = 1}^m a_i\Big)x + \sum_{i = 1}^m \Big(\prod_{j = i + 1}^m a_j\Big) b_i$$ Considering the $(\ell_1, \ldots, \ell_m) \in \{f, g\}^m$ as uniformly distributed and taking the expectation over all such ordered tuples, you essentially end up with a sum of $2^m$ terms as above and now you will essentially have a counting problem to solve.

Comment: Functions have domains and codomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to the first part of the problem.

Note, that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the sequence of random variables defined as $C_1(x),C_2(x),C_3(x), \dots$ can be viewed as a Markov Chain.  The expectation can thus be calculated recursively using the recursive structure of the Markov Chain. In fact we have
$$\mathbb{E}[C_m(x)] = \mathbb{E}[C_1(\mathbb{E}[C_{m-1}(x)])] = \frac{f(\mathbb{E}[C_{m-1}(x)])+g(\mathbb{E}[C_{m-1}(x)])}{2}$$

Comment: I will update my answer if i figure out a solution to the second part of the problem